# Не открываются свойства микрофона в Windows

Tags: windows

https://youtu.be/6pR2qMX9Zkg

вот что происходит открываю звуки->запись тыкаю микрофон и оно вылетает. Так со всеми входами кроме виртуальных. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Раз уж мы на стэке, давайте решать эту проблему по-программистски. Готовы перейти на Linux?

Comment: Пытался но на линуксе нет фотошопа, а через "вайн" он очень кривой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я из прошлого, смотри как надо было сделать:

Заходить с свойства, потом система, потом звук, там где панель ввод открываешь свойства устройства и сбоку тыкаешь на дополнительные свойства устройства. Готово!

Answer (score 0):

Тоже самое в windows 10. Выход установи RecordPad Sound Recorder (у меня версия 9.03). Нажми Options и кнопку Open Record Mixer windows. Откроется такие же настройки (что и командой mmsys.cpl) только уже можно и в свойства зайти микрофона и сменить микрофон по умолчанию.